# Why my resource on Laravel is not working as expected?

Tags: laravel

I have a simple resource:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources\Integration\PayGo;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class VendaVenderResource extends JsonResource
{
    public $preserveKeys = true;

    protected $method;

    public function paymentMethod(string $method = null)
    {
        $this->method = $method;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        dd("ENTROU");
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
        ];
    }
}
```

When i made a simple service that call this Resource in the middle of the code like this:

```
    $vendaVenderResource = (new Resources\Integration\PayGo\VendaVenderResource($entry));

    dd("PASSOU");
```

This method toArray() from Resource is not executing and is not entering in my **dd("ENTROU");** for testing purpose, it is executing this **dd("PASSOU");** after the Resource i don't know why!!

What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: because `toArray` isn't being called yet ... you would have to do something with the resource for that method to be called ... only the constructor is called here

Comment: I have a similar code in another application and works fine, i don't think is that, in resources we pass the data like a construct.

Comment: no that is why ... that method is never called at this point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call your resource this way. Resources should be called thought an api (so the accept json will be sent, and laravel should know what to return ....

If you want to use resources in this way, you should use the method **resolve** `(new Resources\Integration\PayGo\VendaVenderResource($entry))->resolve();`

Ps.: Entrou e passou are so huebrbr kkkkkk

Comment: kkkkkkkkkkkkkk eu fui descobrir isso depois, quando coloquei na API funcionou :D. Thanks work well!